# Формирование JSP страницы

Tags: java, jsp, servlet

Насколько нормальной является практика создания динамический jsp страниц с точки зрения нагрузки на сервер, если при каждом запросе страницы происходит проверка сессии зарегистрированного пользователя, сверка его прав, сбор нужной информации, ведь при этом происходит и множество запросов в БД? Получается достаточно ресурсоемко, но придумать варианты облегчить это все не получается.

Comment: Ну для этого она и предназначена как минимум.   
Что имеется ввиду динамической? Вы проверяете слэш изменяете, что-то ajax'ом или просто подтягиваете при каждой загрузке страницы множество информации из базы?

Comment: 1) Проверить, залогинен ли пользователь 2) Валидация его сессии 3) Проверка прав доступа 4) Генерация меню для этого типа пользователя 5) Подгрузка запрашиваемого контента - каждый шаг это несколько запросов в базу. И мне кажется, если увеличится кол-во пользователей одновременно, задержка будет существенной у них

Comment: все эти запросы в базу происходят еще на уровне контроллера или какого-то сервлета, до того как они попадут на jsp, за исключение прав доступа sping security(тут не уверен).  Проверка авторизации, серверная валидация и прочее. jsp только отображает их состояние. в этом случае она не является динамическая, это статическая jsp. Даже если вы изменяете что-то аля аджаксом, на нагруженность это все равно не влияет.  Если проблема с скоростью загрузки, это вопрос оптимизации кода, а не количества ресурсов на jsp, так как она отображает состояние разных ентити в базе, а не ищет их.

Answer (score 0):

JSP в любом случае является динамической, поскольку транслируется в сервлет вместе со скриплетами / JSTL.

HttpSession живет внутри WEB контейнера, при работе с ним обращения к базе данных не происходит.

Если для получения полной информации о пользователе вам нужно сделать большое кол-во запросов к базе данных, то это вопрос к архитектуре вашего приложения, а не JSP. Вы можете хранить какие-то данные в памяти, оптимизировать SQL запросы, кэшировать на уровне приложения или базы данных и прочее. Несколько SQL запросов, если они оптимизированы, не станут узким местом вашего приложения.